# How can I compare two similarities obtained using two different data sets?

Tags: algorithm, similarity

I am trying to calculate User-User similarities through cosine similarity by using two different data sets (Users are same just that features being considered for obtaining similarities are different among the data sets) . Now, is there a way I could tell how similar these two data sets are based on the similarity values?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer here should be no, unless there are no common features in the two data sets(if they differ only in units, you can normalize them both and use them). For e.g., you cannot recommend movies to a user using two different data sets where one contains only the age and gender of the users, while the other contains only the favorite genres the users like, and compare the two results.

Also, your query vector should also have the same features as the data set that the similarity search algorithm uses.

In your case, if the query has features of both the data sets, you can find the k Nearest Neighbors in both of them (for e.g.) and return them both i.e. 2k results. But you cannot choose among the two pairs of k NNs regarding which is the best. I also would recommend finding a way to merge the two data sets instead of following this approach.

Edit:
I misinterpreted the question. If you have the same users in both the data sets, you should merge them (preferably using the User ID column if any) and then use the new data set to calculate similarity among users.

Your question about the similarity of data sets does not make much sense in this context.